# How to delete record automatically after date

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

is it possible to make in phpmyadmin table which will have:

"id, text1, text2, date"

And after "date" it will delete this record automatically?

Comment: Use the trigger of mysql.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySQL Event like this,

```
mysqli_query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");

mysqli_query("CREATE EVENT rec ON DATE() DO DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value;");
```